# ¿Cómo puedo insertar filas faltantes en un DataFrame?

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, pandas

¿Cómo puedo insertar filas en un DataFrame de Pandas en Python 2.7?

Actualmente estoy cargando los datos desde una query de MySQL:

`data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)`

El DataFrame tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
timestamp  data1 data2
1515581720 12    23
1515581721 23    34
1515581723 45    34
1515581724 45    23
```

Me gustaría saber, si es posible insertar una nueva fila sobre la 
información obtenida desde mysql.

En el caso anterior falta el registro `1515581722`.

Debería quedar por tanto:

```
timestamp  data1 data2
1515581720 12    23
1515581721 23    34
1515581722 NULL  NULL
1515581723 45    34
1515581724 45    23
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no he malentendido lo que pretendes, para agregar todas las filas que falten entre los valores del índice o de una columna dada lo más simple es usar `pandas.reindex`. Si es una columna previamente la convertimos en el indice con `pandas.DataFrame.set_index`.

- Si tu columna es de tipo `int` puedes generar el nuevo índice con `numpy.arange`:

  ```
  import sys

  if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
      from StringIO import StringIO # Python 2
  else:
      from io import StringIO       # Python 3

  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np


  data = StringIO(
  '''timestamp,data1,data2
  1515581720,12,23
  1515581721,23,34
  1515581723,45,34
  1515581724,45,23
  ''')

  df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col='timestamp')
  ```

  Con esto tenemos un ejemplo como el que provees:

  ```
  >>> df
              data1  data2
  timestamp               
  1515581720     12     23
  1515581721     23     34
  1515581723     45     34
  1515581724     45     23
  ```

  Ahora vamos a genera el nuevo index:

  ```
  >>> idx = np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1)
  >>> df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan)
  >>> df

               data1  data2
  timestamp               
  1515581720   12.0   23.0
  1515581721   23.0   34.0
  1515581722    NaN    NaN
  1515581723   45.0   34.0
  1515581724   45.0   23.0
  ```
- Si tu columna es de tipo `datetime64`, `pandas.timestamp`, `datetime.datetime` o cualquier objeto date-like puedes usar [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) para generar el nuevo índice:

  ```
  import sys

  if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
      from StringIO import StringIO # Python 2
  else:
      from io import StringIO       # Python 3

  import pandas as pd


  data = StringIO(
  '''timestamp,data1,data2
  1515581720,12,23
  1515581721,23,34
  1515581723,45,34
  1515581724,45,23
  ''')

  df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col='timestamp')
  df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
  ```

  Con lo que tenemos:

  ```
  >>> df
                       data1  data2
  timestamp                        
  2018-01-10 10:55:20   12.0   23.0
  2018-01-10 10:55:21   23.0   34.0
  2018-01-10 10:55:23   45.0   34.0
  2018-01-10 10:55:24   45.0   23.0
  ```

  Ahora podemos generar las filas que faltan con:

  ```
  >>> idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="s")
  >>> df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan)
  >>> df.index.rename('timestamp', inplace=True)
  >>> df

                       data1  data2
  timestamp                        
  2018-01-10 10:55:20   12.0   23.0
  2018-01-10 10:55:21   23.0   34.0
  2018-01-10 10:55:22    NaN    NaN
  2018-01-10 10:55:23   45.0   34.0
  2018-01-10 10:55:24   45.0   23.0
  ```

Comment: Estoy validando tu ejemplo @FJSevilla pero quede estancado en la primera parte, python me arroja error con las comillas :/

Comment: @Alejandro para poder ayudar necesitamos más información. Muestra la traza completa del error y es importante que digas el tipo de los datos de cada columna y si timestamp es o no el índice de tu dataframe. Puedes obtenerlos con `print(df.dtype)`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la primera parte de mis ejemplos son solo para obtener un DataFrame similar al que muestras. El problema puede ser debido a IO, el código es para Python 3, espera un momento, voy a editar. Para emularlo todo en Python 2 solo hay que modificar el import de IO

Comment: claro quiero tener claro tu ejemplo para llevarlo acabo mi problema principal, estoy trabajando con Python2.7, el error es TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str.

Comment: Corregido Alejandro, ahora el código funciona tanto en Python 2 como en Python 3. Simplemente el import para Python 2 debería ser `from StringIO import StringIO`. Disculpa, trabajo en Python 3 y se me pasó ese detalle.

Comment: Funciono perfecto, maestro!!

Comment: tengo una pequeña duda... :/

Comment: @Alejandro ¿de que se trata?

Comment: De acuerdo como lo planteaste, me funciono sin problemas, solo que me @FJSevilla agrego los nuevos registros en blanco (Index), supongo que es por que mi query (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time+(timezone*3600)) as Fecha, time...) y la lista luego muestra la columna Fecha, la que tiene formato datetime (Y/m/d H:m:s ), supongo que es posible aplicarlo sobre formato datetime?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71547/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-alejandro).